# Lifetime of the module variables in Python

Tags: python

Could you please explain me these basics.
`server_init() -> start_db() -> it makes variable state = 5 -> server starts start_client() in 2 seconds -> client calls get_state() and gets value = 5`
Is it right that client sees 5? How long will module variables live?
Thanks.

**server.py:**

```
def t3():
    time.sleep(2)
    start_client()

def server_init():
    start_db()
    thread = threading.Thread(target=t3)
    thread.start()

server_init()
```

**db.py**

```
state = 0
q = queue.Queue()

def t2():
    global state
    while state < 5:
        state += 1
        global q
    q.put(state)

def start_db():
    thread = threading.Thread(target=t2)
    thread.start()

def get_state():
    print('q.get(): %s' % q.get())
    print('state: %s' % state)
```

**client.py**

```
def t1():
    get_state()  # prints 5

def start_client():
    print('start_client')
    thread = threading.Thread(target=t1)
    thread.start()
```

Comment: What did you expect to happen instead? Did you find it surprising that `state` is still `5`? Nothing resets the value back to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modules are stored in the global mapping `sys.modules`. As long as there is *any reference* available to a module object, it'll remain alive. Typically, modules are not removed from `sys.modules` until the Python interpreter shuts down.

Comment: Can I say if the server has import start_client and client has import get_state that I have a reference from the server to the db all this time?

Comment: @Igor: the moment you import a module for the first time all the top-level code (including `state=0`) is executed and the resulting names are stored on the module object. So *any* code that imports the `db` module will bring the global name `state` into being.